# Display names when input text is separated by # in C++?

Tags: c++, file, c++11, input, getline

So, input text of list.txt file is in the form: FirstName LastName#Age
My task is to read the list.txt file of four lines of the above form, and output the name with the largest age. I will write my solution below, which works, but only if # is removed and inputs are separated by space. Not sure how to do it with the # being present? I understand i can use getline(), just not sure how?
Eg: Alpha Beta#22
Gama Delta#10
and the output should be the name of the oldest person followed by his age. Please orient me towards a an actual correct solution. Thank you in advanceee! :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream ins;   // declare an input file stream object

    ins.open("list.txt");  // open the file
    if (ins.fail()) {     // check if there was an error
        cout << "Error opening file";
        return -1;
    }

    string maxName;   // 
    int maxAge = 0; // 



    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {   // read four lines from the file
        string firstName, lastName;
        int age;
        ins >> age;  // read three variables from the stream line

        if (nr > maxAge) {   // update the current maximum if greater
            maxAge = age;
            maxName = firstName + " " + lastName;
        }
    }

    ins.close();   // close the file

    cout << " The oldest person is: " << maxName
        << " : " << maxAge << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please search the internet for "Comma Separated Values C++ String".  Although your code is not separated by commas, you should be able to adapt those examples to suit your needs.  Hint:  use `std::getline(input_file, text_string, delimiter_character);`

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code for you.

```
struct Record
{
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    unsigned int age;  // Ever hear of a negative age?
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
    input >> r.first_name;
    std::getline(input, r.last_name, '#');
    input >> r.age;
    return input;
}
```

Here's the input loop:

```
std::vector<Record> database;
Record r;
while (ins >> r)
{
    database.push_back(r);
}
```

Since the first name and last name are space separated, the `operator>>` can be use to read in the first name.

Reading in the last name uses a form of `std::getline` that has a delimiter parameter.  The function will read characters, storing them into the string, until the delimiter is read.  The function does not store the delimiter.

Since the input stream position is past the '#', the `operator>>` can be used to read in the age.

The next read will skip the remaining newline (because it is whitespace), and read the first name of the second record, and so forth.

The `operator>>` is overloaded in the `Record` structure to increase encapsulation and reduce tightly coupled modules.  The `Record` knows about its members and outside entities shouldn't.